# dojo enhanced grid filter - programatically set column A greater than some number

Tags: javascript, dojo, grid

I'm trying to set a filter on a dojo grid programatically so that some column be greater than some number.
I have a quantity column and I wish to set a filter so that quantity be greater (or different) than zero.

Thanks!

So the code would look like this:

```
dojo.require("dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid");
var storage = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({data: data});
var layout = [ { field: 'id', name: '# ID', width: '60px' },
               { field: 'name', name: 'Nume produs', width: '200px' },
               { field: 'qty', name: 'QTY', alwaysEditing: true, editable: true }
];
var grid = new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid({
    store: storage,
    structure: layout,
    plugins: { filter : true },
}, 'grid');
grid.startup();
```

I'm guessing I should do a filter or a query but I really don't know how to compare two things, the only thing I found out is that I can use a query with RegEx but.. that's all

Comment: Added some code in the main post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing

```
var grid = new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid({
    query: { 'qty' : new RegExp('^[1-9]+[0-9]*$') }, 
    store: storage,
    structure: layout,
    plugins: { filter : true },
}, 'grid');
```

works but I believe it's rather inefficient and I hoped for a nicer, cleaner, faster solution.

Comment: Yes, it's unfortunate that filtering is resstricted to RegExps. Would it be possible to use a different data store implementation?

Comment: Yes, sure. As long it's also write-able. Why ? Other data stores have the implementation of comparing columns to some data ?
Basically, the "filter" plugin is able to do this BUT I can't find any example on how to programatically do it. I can only do it by point and click.

Comment: I was just thinking that with e.g. a JsonRestStore you could already filter the elements in the back-end - that is when your grid requests *all* the elements, you would just send the *filtered elements* to it.

Comment: I`m making an JavaScript-only powered application :)

Comment: Hehe, then the only thing I see that you could do is subclass ItemFileWriteStore or filter on your own by iterating over the column cells and hiding the cells via CSS maybe.

Comment: No, hiding via css would kill other grid's features (like pagination for example). For now, the solution with RegExp works ok

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I ended up doing something similar:

The basic idea is to add an invisible column.  When the value you want to test meets your criteria (greater than some value, or in my case within some range) then set the invisible column to 'Y', otherwise set it to 'N'.  Then the filter is easy: invisibleColumn: 'Y'.

The following displays a grid with Column_B values between 100-500.  Click the button to activate a filter to display only values between 150-350.  It is a complete working example in three parts (javascript, HTML, CSS):

The JavaScript (script.js)

```
dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
dojo.require("dojox.grid.DataGrid");
dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore");


dojo.ready(function(){  
var appLayout = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
    id: "appLayout"
}, "appLayout");

var data = {
  'items': [
    {'Column_A': 'alpha', 'Column_B': 100},
    {'Column_A': 'beta',  'Column_B': 200},
    {'Column_A': 'gamma', 'Column_B': 300},
    {'Column_A': 'delta', 'Column_B': 400},
    {'Column_A': 'epsilon', 'Column_B': 500}
  ]
};
var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({
    data: data      
});


var layout = [[ 
  {name : 'A', field : 'Column_A', width : '125px'},
  {name : 'B', field : 'Column_B', width : '125px%'}
]];


var grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
    structure : layout,
    store: store,
    queryOptions: {ignoreCase: true}
});


var filterButton = new dijit.form.Button({
    label: "Filter",
    onClick: function () {
        var determineRange = function (items, request) {
            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
                items[i].invisibleColumn = (items[i].Column_B > 150 && items[i].Column_B < 350) ? 'Y' : 'N';
            }
            grid.filter({invisibleColumn: 'Y'});
        };
        store.fetch({onComplete: determineRange});  
    }
});


filterButton.placeAt(appLayout.domNode);
grid.placeAt(appLayout.domNode);


appLayout.startup();
});
```

The html (index.html)

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Filter by range</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="screen"/>   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.1/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.1/dijit/themes/claro/document.css" />   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.1/dojox/layout/resources/ExpandoPane.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.1/dojox/grid/resources/claroGrid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.1/dojox/grid/enhanced/resources/claro/EnhancedGrid.css">

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.1/dojo/dojo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>

  <body class="claro">
    <div id="appLayout"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And finally the CSS (style.css)

```
html, body {
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  margin: 0; padding: 0; 
  overflow: hidden;     
}   

#appLayout {
  width 100%; height: 100%;
}
```